# Save the video while making a video call using AWS Kinesis Video stream with WebRTC

Tags: webrtc, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-firehose, amazon-kinesis-video-streams

Im using aws kinesis video stream webRTC for making a video chat in reactjs .Everything is working fine.But i want to store the video in s3 bucket.How should i implement this video storage?

Comment: Did you achieved this functionality, please post if yes!

Comment: Slightly off-top question here, but do you have an example for getting a kinesis video stream webRTC to start/work from the MASTER role?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do the following:

1. Get the video stream from WebRTC
2. Use KVS Producer's PutMedia, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesisvideostreams/latest/dg/API_dataplane_PutMedia.html.
3. Retrieve them the frames with GetMedia, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesisvideostreams/latest/dg/API_dataplane_GetMedia.html.

Note: under the hood, KVS Producer uses S3

Comment: Is there any chances to save the video while using kinesis signaling channel.

Comment: AWSlabs KVS npm package(https://www.npmjs.com/package/amazon-kinesis-video-streams-webrtc) doesn't allow any functionality to create a video stream. It only provides Signaling Channel class.

Answer (score 0):

Since the connection can be peer to peer, you have to store the video yourself to S3. You can try to use the KVS producer sdk for that purpose: https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-video-streams-producer-sdk-cpp